# Grunt task for combining multiple Jquery ready functions into single ready function

Tags: javascript, jquery, gruntjs

I have ready functions spread across multiple files which I am looking to merge and minify. Is there a grunt task which will merge all ready into one function ?

```
// file1.js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".class1").click(function () {
        // Some Action
    })
})


// file2.js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".class3").on("blur", function () {
        // Some Action
    })
})

// file3.js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".class2").on("change", function () {
        // Some Action
    })
})

// file4.js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".class3").click(function () {
        // Some Action
    })
})
```

I am looking for something like ...

```
// file.js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".class1").click(function () {
        // Some Action
    })

    $(".class3").on("blur", function () {
        // Some Action
    })

    $(".class2").on("change", function () {
        // Some Action
    })

    $(".class3").click(function () {
        // Some Action
    })
})
```

Will it harm the performance if I just run grunt task to combine all the files and have multiple ready functions in a file merged like this using grunt-contrib-uglify ?

```
// file.js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".class1").click(function () {
        // Some Action
    })
})

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".class3").on("blur", function () {
        // Some Action
    })
})

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".class2").on("change", function () {
        // Some Action
    })
})

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".class3").click(function () {
        // Some Action
    })
})
```

Thank you for checking this question out. Have a great day. Sorry if this is a repeat question. Posting this question because could not find the answer anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

You can use grunt-jquery-ready which will do what you want.

You should concat first all your files and then use this grunt plugin in this way. I tested this and It works

```html
grunt.initConfig({
  'jquery-ready' : {
      path: 'path_to_your_folder/your_script_file.js',
      runSync: false
  }
 
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-jquery-ready');
 
  grunt.registerTask('default', "jquery-ready");
});
```

as a result after executing this I got my file in this format:

```html
$(document).ready(function(){
  all the content of my script.js file is placed here automatically. 
});
```

Please refer to the main website for more information:

[Wrapping your concatenated .js file into ready function](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-jquery-ready)